# /dev/fvm is not found although VT-x is enabled

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I'm trying to run my app in android studio, and it's giving me an error "Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings..." shown in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ddlg.png)

I've checked my BIOS settings, and virtualization is enabled. I also ran securable.exe for doublechecking and everything seems is fine 
([Link for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewG0B.png))

I'm stuck. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (`Any suggestions would be helpful` a (decent) spelling checker would spare everyone the likes of `vitualization is enbaled`.) Please include the gist of information linked *in the question* (*one* reason being links may go stale).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:
This error seems to be like..virtualization of hard disk is not enabled. Reboot your system..while rebooting enter into boot setup..there you can see "virtualization"--please set it to "Enabled" or "ON". As your emulator uses some hard disk memory for its use(this memory should be dedicated to emulator), we need to enable virtualization.